# Getting data from MEXC API

Tags: python

Getting data from MEXC API.
I need to get account assets data from MEXC with Python.

I am struggling with authorization. Code that I tried:

```py
import requests, hmac, hashlib, time

api_key = 'abcde'
api_secret = 'abcde'

# API endpoint
url = 'https://contract.mexc.com/api/v1/private/account/assets'

# Generate signature
timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
prehash = 'GET' + url + 'access_key=' + api_key + '&t=' + timestamp
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), prehash.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'api-key': api_key,
    't': timestamp,
    'sign': signature
}

# Send GET request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```